# Modify Node.js req object parameters

Tags: node.js, express, javascript

So as usual, I tried to find this question on SO but still no luck.

I am aware that the answer is "Yes, you CAN modify the req object" but nothing is said about the req object parameters.

For example the following code will throw an error:

```
app.get('/search', function(req, res) {
   req.param('q') = "something";
});
```

Error:

```
ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

I imagine this has something to do with the property not having a 'SET' method or something along those lines.

There are a few scenarios where this could come in handy.

1. A service that turns quick-links into full blown requests and proxies those out.
2. Simply modifying the parameters before sending it off to another function that you have no desire to modify.

Onto the question, **Is there a way to modify the req object parameters?**

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Rather than:

```
req.param('q') = "something";
```

You'll need to use:

```
req.params.q = "something";
```

The first one is trying to set a value on the return value of the param function, not the parameter itself.

It's worth noting the [req.param()](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.param) method retrieves values from `req.body`, `req.params` and `req.query` all at once and in that order, but to set a value you need to specify which of those three it goes in:

```
req.body.q = "something";
// now: req.param('q') === "something"
req.query.r = "something else";
// now: req.param('r') === "something else"
```

That said unless you're permanently modifying something submitted from the client it might be better to put it somewhere else so it doesn't get mistaken for input from the client by any third party modules you're using.

Comment: Oh, silly me! I could of swore I tried it your way and got the same result but I used your example and it made a liar out of me. Thanks! Edit: In one case, tricking the third party module is exactly my goal.

Comment: I think if some parameter in `params` has already a value (e.g: `foo: 'some value'`), it is not possible to change it's value by calling `req.params.foo = 'bar'`, but as @roy-reiss said it is possible by calling `req.body.foo = 'bar'`. It is confusing as if it has no value before you can change it by calling `req.params`. Don't know it is a bug or what.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative approaches to set params in request (use any):

```
                    req.params.model = 'Model';
Or
                    req.params['model'] = 'Model';
Or
                    req.body.name = 'Name';
Or
                    req.body['name'] = 'Name';
Or
                    req.query.ids = ['id'];
Or
                    req.query['ids'] = ['id'];
```

Now get params as following:

```
        var model = req.param('model');
        var name = req.param('name');
        var ids = req.param('ids');
```

Answer (score 1):

One can also imagine that the left-hand side is not a variable or property, so it makes no sense to try to assign a value to it. If you want to change a query param you have to modify the property in the `req.query` object.

```
req.query.q = 'something';
```

The same goes for `req.body` and `req.params`.