# Sails.js calling one controller action from another and passing additional params in req.body

Tags: model-view-controller, sails.js, waterline

I need to call a controller action from another action. So far, I have not been required to pass any additional params and the call

sails.controllers.modelName.actionName(req, res)

does the job. However, this time I need to add  new param to req.body for the controller action to be called. Is there any way to do that in sails ?

I did try the trick specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18801661/modify-node-js-req-object-parameters) but the problem is that the changes I make in the action are lost when I call the other controller action

**EDIT:** It's working if I try to access the param using req.body in the other controller action but not if I try to access it using req.params.all()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not the best practice for writing re-usable code in Sails.  If you find yourself wanting to call one controller from another, you should move the shared code into a [service](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Services) and call the service method from *both* controllers.

In any case, Sails doesn't allow you to modify request params directly.  You can modify `req.body`, but really the only thing you should modify in the request is `req.options`, which was designed for that purpose.  This way you keep an accurate representation of what was actually received in the request.