# Sails call one controller from another controller

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am having two controllers, `SocketController` and `ProjectController`
`SocketController` has method getData(data)
`ProjectController` has method addProject(data)
I need to call addProject() from getData() method.
I tried using `sails.controllers.ProjectController.addProject(data)` but I got following error:

Cannot find method addProject of undefined

I searched for alternative ways to call another controller using `services` in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25183819/sails-js-calling-one-controller-action-from-another-and-passing-additional-param) but that was of no help to me. Is there any other way to get this work?

Comment: Shouldn't those be models?

Comment: use `sails.controllers.project.addProject(data)`, because if you remember generating the api, you didi it with `sails generate api project` and the name ProjectController was assigned by sails to your controller file

Answer (score 16):

Controllers are just Node modules that export public methods.  You can `require` them like anything else.  So assuming your methods are correctly exposed with `module.exports`, this will work:

```
/* ProjectController */

module.exports = {
  addProject: function(data) {
    // ...
  }
};
```

---

```
/* SocketController */

// Assuming ProjectController.js exists in the same directory (default for Sails)
var projectController = require('./ProjectController');

module.exports = {
  index: function(req, res) {
    // ...
    projectController.addProject(...);
  }
};
```

*Edit:* I will add that using services is a better place to keep common functionality like your example.  Services allow complex logic to be decoupled from the controller layer and reused by other areas of the application with ease.  Controllers should generally be reserved for handling HTTP requests from the client and passing the data to the service or model layers for manipulating the database.  I believe Sails also makes services global by default so you don't have to worry about confusing `require` paths.

Comment: The controller is available in the global "sails" object, so I don't see why you can't just use sails.controllers.project in your example, instead of doing a require().

Comment: sails.controllers is gone (sails 1.x) ... only the require approach works now.

Answer (score 5):

Controller functions are also accessible through the global sails object, without use of require, however a function from ProjectController will be found under:

`sails.controllers.project.addProject`

instead of

`sails.controllers.ProjectController.addProject`

Anyways you might want to consider having shared functionality in either services or models, as was pointed out previously.