# @nestjs/swagger: Is it possible to prevent phishing?

Tags: node.js, swagger, nestjs, swagger-ui, nestjs-swagger

I'm using [@nestjs/swagger](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/introduction) in the Nest.js application to generate Swagger documentation.

In the documentation we have a simple example like

```js
      const config = new DocumentBuilder()
        .setTitle('Cats example')
        .setDescription('The cats API description')
        .setVersion('1.0')
        .addTag('cats')
        .build();
      const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);
      SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, document);
```

With this implementation, I faced the security issue, which can expose attackers to phishing. For example, we have a swagger page

```
https://petstore.swagger.io/
```

Attackers can add a query parameter in URL like

```
https://petstore.swagger.io/?url=https://27.rs/card.yaml#/default/get_
```

That can lead to security issues. Is there any way to prevent it? Can we disable the query parameters for the Swagger URL, or clean it? To convert

https://petstore.swagger.io/?url=https://27.rs/card.yaml#/default/get_ => https://petstore.swagger.io/

As a 4-th parameter `SwaaggerModule.setup` function can receive options. I have tried to do something with them but still no result. Here are possible parameters

```js
export interface SwaggerCustomOptions {
  explorer?: boolean;
  swaggerOptions?: Record<string, any>;
  customCss?: string;
  customCssUrl?: string;
  customJs?: string;
  customfavIcon?: string;
  swaggerUrl?: string;
  customSiteTitle?: string;
  validatorUrl?: string;
  url?: string;
  urls?: Record<'url' | 'name', string>[];
}
```

I can see also the open issue in [GitHub](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4332) regarding this question.
There are mentioned about the usage of `window.history.replaceState(null, "", window.location.pathname);`. How it can be used in @nestjs/swagger?

Comment: how did you build that swagger page? because the one generated by `@nestjs/swagger` doesn't this issue

Comment: You can try to run the Nest.js server and build a swagger document as we have in the documentation. After you can open the swagger page and add query parameter such as `url=https://27.rs/card.yaml#/default/get_`. For example, your URL can look like `http://localhost:3000/api/doc/url=https://27.rs/card.yaml#/default/get_`

Comment: For the locally, you can face a CORS error. The goal is to prevent providing query parameters to prevent security issues.

Comment: you're right! I don't think that we can fix that as a user of `@nestjs/swagger` due to [this line](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/blob/491b168cbff3003191e55ee96e77e69d8c1deb66/lib/swagger-module.ts#L55) (in case of `express` http adpater)

Comment: the far I could get is disallow the `url` query param for our swagger page, ie., if you request `http://localhost:3000/api?url=https://27.rs/card.yaml#/default/get_` you'll get 403
I didn't succeed overwriting this param value (following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18801661/))

Comment: Yup. Actually, as a temporary solution, I have added something like
 ` 
 app.use(
    `/${swaggerPath}`,
    (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
      if (Object.keys(req.query).length) {
        res.redirect(`/${swaggerPath}`);
      } else {
        next();
      }
    },
  );`

before calling `SwaggerModule.setup(swaggerPath, app, document);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't found any solution in @nestjs/swagger and I can see the open issue in GitHub

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4332#issuecomment-867574178

As a temporary solution, I have added the following part of the code to handle the requests before rendering the Swagger document.

```
   app.use(swaggerPath, (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
      // A temporary solution to prevent security issues with query params
      // Can be removed when into the swagger module will be added ability to turn off query parameters of URL
      if (Object.keys(req.query).length) {
        res.redirect(swaggerPath);
      } else {
        next();
      }
    });
```

Where swaggerPath is something like `/api/doc`, or your swagger path.